# List Comprehension Indexing

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Suppose for example you have the list

```
a = [['hand', 'head'], ['phone', 'wallet'], ['lost', 'stock']]
```

and another list

```
b = ['phone', 'lost']
```

And you want to find a list `c`, that contains the indices of the rows in `a` (thinking of `a` as a 2D matrix) whose first column is a value in `b`. So in this case

```
c = [1, 2]
```

I tried to use the following list comprehensions

```
c = [i if a[i][0] in b for i in range(0, 1)]
c = [i if a[i][0] in b]
```

But both of these were invalid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
c = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v[0] in b]
```

`enumerate()` gives you both the index and the value of the iterable you pass in. Note that the `if` test goes at the end; list comprehensions should be written in the same order that you would use when nesting loops:

```
c = []
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if v[0] in b:
        c.append(i)
```

You really want to make `b` a set:

```
b = set(b)
```

to make membership testing a O(1) constant time operation as opposed to a O(n) linear time test against a list.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [['hand', 'head'], ['phone', 'wallet'], ['lost', 'stock']]
>>> b = {'phone', 'lost'}  # set literal
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v[0] in b]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: @Jon: Just because the OP has a off-by-one error doesn't mean you need to edit that same error into my answer. :-P

Comment: Was going to, then thought better of it, then got distracted, so discarded it, which then wasn't actually a discard it appears ;) [one of those days :(]

Answer (score 0):

First the array the start from 0.
So c must be:

```
c=[1,2]
```

if you need to do it with a list compression the solution can be:

```
c=[pos for pos, val_a in enumerate(a) for val_b_to_check in val_a if val_b_to_check in b ]
```

Comment: This would test for *all* values in the row, the OP wanted to test only for the *first* element.

Comment: If you did want to test all values in each row, using a set intersection would be faster (provided `b` is a set):  `[i for i, v in enumerate(a) if b & v]`

Comment: You need to cast to set also on v. [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if b & set(v)]

Comment: No you don't. Not in recent Python versions.

Comment: Martijn, you are right. There is autocast to set (a least in python 2.7.4 or above)

Comment: Python 2.6 and above; it doesn't need to cast anything; it simply iterates over the second operand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numpy to do this as well:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([['hand', 'head'], ['phone', 'wallet'], ['lost', 'stock']])
>>> b = np.array(['phone', 'lost'])
>>> np.in1d(a[:,0],b)
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Or, if you want the indices:

```
>>> np.where(np.in1d(a[:,0],b))[0].tolist()
[1, 2]
```